# Unique month+year combinations in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, unique, array-formulas

I have a column of dates in Google Sheets, and I want to create a list of the month+year combinations. I did a search and found this formula that works but when there's a blank cell in the date column then it adds the date 01/12/3799 into the list of month+year combinations.

```
=UNIQUE(ARRAYFORMULA(DATE(YEAR(A1:A10), MONTH(A1:A10), 1))
```

How can I make this formula work without producing that odd date? Thanks.

Comment: I found the problem comes down to the YEAR and MONTH functions. They treat blank cells as numbers, blank month=12 and blank year=3799. I managed to figure out how to get it to return an empty cell rather than this odd date by adding in a check to see if a cell in the range is blank:

=UNIQUE(ARRAYFORMULA(if(isblank(A1:A10),, DATE(YEAR(A1:A10), MONTH(A1:A10), 1))))

Now the only remaning problem is the empty cell it returns in the output list. How can I get it to not return an empty cell?

Comment: Ok this formula does the job, but I wonder if someone has a cleaner solution to this problem? Thanks.

=UNIQUE(filter( ARRAYFORMULA(if(isblank(A1:A10),,DATE(YEAR(A1:A10),MONTH(A1:A10),1))) , ARRAYFORMULA(if(isblank(A1:A10),,DATE(YEAR(A1:A10),MONTH(A1:A10),1))) <>""))

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: I don't think there is much of an improvement from your last formula. You could post your solution as an answer so it can be accepted (by yourself) and upvoted by others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem comes down to the YEAR and MONTH functions. They treat blank cells as numbers, blank month=12 and blank year=3799.

This formula does the job:

```
=UNIQUE(filter( ARRAYFORMULA(if(isblank(A1:A10),,DATE(YEAR(A1:A10),MONTH(A1:A10),1))) , ARRAYFORMULA(if(isblank(A1:A10),,DATE(YEAR(A1:A10),MONTH(A1:A10),1))) <>""))
```